# created an virtual environment but vscode cannot find it

Tags: visual-studio-code

I created the virtual environment in command prompt by typing "py -3 -m venv .venv" and ".venv\scripts\activate" in windows command prompt. But it does not show up in the "select interpreter" options. I was supposed to see the python 3.11.1 ('.venv':venv) in the "select interpreter" option.

Answer (score 0):

solution [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#:%7E:text=From%20within%20VS%20Code%2C%20you,environment%20types%3A%20Venv%20or%20Conda.)

1. open the Command Palette (Ctrl+Shift+P)
2. type to search for "Python: Create Environment", select the command.
3. choose environment type "Venv"